# An example showing the compactness is essential

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

If $S$ is a compact surface oriented by a 2-form $\eta$. Then $\eta$ is not an exact form. In fact, if $\exists \omega$ a 1-form s.t. $\eta = d \omega$, we'd have by Stoke's Theorem and $\partial S = \emptyset$:

$$ \int_S \eta = \int_S d\omega = \int_{\partial S} \omega = \int_{\emptyset} \omega = 0$$

Then $\eta_p = 0$ for some $p \in S$ what contradicts the fact of $S$ beeing oriented by $\eta$.

I'm looking for an example showing that the result is false if $S$ isn't compact.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for instance $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with volume form $dx\wedge dy=d(xdy)$.

In fact, the second de Rham cohomology group of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is trivial, which shows that any differential form of top degree (which is automatically a closed form) is exact.